# How to use the same MySQL and same PHPMyAdmin for multiple containers like Joomla! and WordPress?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm a newbie to docker and I would like to ask a question about how to have one Joomla! and one WordPress site by using the same MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. I suppose that this has to be with a network but I don't know-how.

**FOR JOOMLA:**

I have this "./joomla/docker-compose.yml" file:

```
version: '3'

services:

    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.1
        restart: always
        env_file: .env
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        restart: always
        container_name: yt_test_mysql_joomla

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "9090:80"
        restart: always
        links:
            - mysql:db
        container_name: yt_test_phpmyadmin_joomla

    joomla:
        image: "joomla:${JOOMLA_VERSION:-5.2.1}-php${PHP_VERSION:-7.3}-apache"
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "8082:80"
        restart: always
        environment: 
            JOOMLA_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
            JOOMLA_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            JOOMLA_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        container_name: yt_test_joomla
        volumes:
            - "./joomla_files/modules/mod_breadcrumbs:/var/www/html/modules/mod_breadcrumbs"
```

and this is my ./joomla/.env file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
MYSQL_USER=sqlusr
MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
MYSQL_DATABASE=joomladb

JOOMLA_VERSION=3.9.15
PHP_VERSION=7.4
```

**FOR WORDPRESS:**

I have this "./wordpress/docker-compose.yml" file:

```
version: '3'

services:

    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.1
        restart: always
        env_file: .env
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
        restart: always
        container_name: yt_test_mysql_wp

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "9091:80"
        restart: always
        links:
            - mysql:db
        container_name: yt_test_phpmyadmin_wp

    wordpress:
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        image: "wordpress:${WP_VERSION:-5.2.1}-php${PHP_VERSION:-7.3}-apache"
        container_name: yt_test_wp
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        env_file: .env
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        volumes:
            - "./wordpress_files/wp-content/plugins/img-src-corrector:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/img-src-corrector"
            - "./wordpress_files/wp-content/plugins/login-as-user:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/login-as-user"
```

and this is my ./wordpress/.env file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
MYSQL_USER=sqlusr
MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpressdb

WP_VERSION=5.3.2
PHP_VERSION=7.4
```

If I run the command `docker-compose up -d` everything works properly with the below URLs.

- http://192.168.99.100:9090 (PHPMyAdmin - Joomla!)
- http://192.168.99.100:9091 (PHPMyAdmin - WordPress)
- http://192.168.99.100:8082 (Joomla)
- http://192.168.99.100:8081 (WordPress)

**So my question are:**

1. Is the above the correct method?
2. How can I have one MySQL only (same port) and one PHPMyAdmin only (same port) for both WordPress and Joomla! instead of having different ports for each one separately (e.g. for PHPMyAdmin I have two different ports instead of one)?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Is the above the correct method?** 
This depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to split these instances and keep the data separated then yes it is the correct way. On the other hand, if you are trying to minimize the efforts for managing MySQL instances then it is not.

If you would like to have one MySQL instance, you need to take care of creating the users and the databases (You cant use the env vars such as  "MYSQL_USER" more then once). One way to manage the users and databases is to create bootstrap files like it is shown below.

sql-scripts.sql

```
# create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `wordpressdb`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `joomladb`;

CREATE USER 'sqlusr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sqlusr_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sqlusr'@'%';
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0.1
COPY ./sql-scripts.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

MySQL compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysqlx
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy
      MYSQL_DATABASE: soso
      MYSQL_USER: soso
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: soso
    restart: always
    container_name: yt_test_mysql_joomla
```

with the above example, the MySQL container will have three databases (soso, wordpressdb, joomladb).

Note that if you split the services into different files you may need to set the network on the containers to enable the communications between the containers